# SVD recommendation : How to split train data and test data? | How to apply SVD in test mode?

Tags: machine-learning, svd, train-test-split

The problem is that I can finish SVD on my whole dataset (movielens user-item rating matrix), but the homework requires splitting train data and test data and I don't know how to do. And if it's in test mode what's the usage of u,s,v (the result of SVD) and how can I calculate the user-item matrix (very very confused).

I can finish the SVD based on the user-item matrix to fulfill it.
Just have no clue about how can I do train and test.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The train-test-split approach is pretty similar for recommendation algorithms. The [surprise documentation](https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html#train-test-split-and-the-fit-method) has fairly general advice.